# Random Up-walk on Young's Lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, random-walks

Starting from the empty partition, $\varnothing$, follow a random up-walk of length $n$ on Young's Lattice, where an edge's transition probability is 1/updegree. For a particular partition, $\lambda$, is it known what the probability of landing at $\lambda$ is? For example, the probability of landing at the partitions:

$\varnothing$ is 1;

(1) is 1;

(2) is $\frac12$, (1, 1) is $\frac12$;

(3) is $\frac14$, (2, 1) is $\frac12$, and (1, 1, 1) is $\frac14$;

(4) is $\frac3{24}$, (3,1) is $\frac7{24}$, (2,2) is $\frac4{24}$, (2,1,1) is $\frac7{24}$, and (1,1,1,1) is $\frac3{24}$.

Cheers! (PS I saw this problem in a class, but wasn't able to find more information about it, so references are also appreciated.)

Minor Update: I've thrown together some rather ugly Mathematica code to generate the probabilities. Partitions[i] outputs the partitions of i in reverse lexicographic and p[i] outputs their corresponding probabilities according to the random up-walk described above. For example, Partitions[3] is {{3}, {2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}} and p[3] is {{1/4, 1/2, 1/4}}.

```
MaxLevel = 17;
p[0] = {{1}}; 
w[0] = {{1}};
For[l = 0, l <= MaxLevel, l++,
 xx = Partitions[l];
 yy = Partitions[l + 1];
 For[i = 1, i <= PartitionsP[l], i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= PartitionsP[l + 1], j++,
    x = Part[xx, i];
    y = Part[yy, j];
    LengthDiff = Length[y] - Length[x];
    If[LengthDiff < 0, A[i, j] = 0, 
     If[LengthDiff == 0 && ! MemberQ[y - x, _?Negative], A[i, j] = 1, 
      If[LengthDiff == 1 && ! MemberQ[y - Append[x, 0], _?Negative], 
       A[i, j] = 1, A[i, j] = 0]]]
    ]
   ]
 B[l] = Table[
    A[i, j], {i, PartitionsP[l]}, {j, PartitionsP[l + 1]}];
 d[l] = #/Total[#] & /@ B[l];
 w[l + 1] = w[l].B[l];
 p[l + 1] = p[l].d[l]
 ]
```

Comment: The numerical results suggest that the common denominator for the probabilities on level $i$ is given by $2 \phi(6^{i-2})$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient.

Comment: for $i=11$ I have $2\phi(6^{i-2}) = 6718464$ but common denominator $33592320 = 5\cdot 2\phi(6^{i-2})$.

Comment: for i = 12 I have $2\phi(6^{i-2}) = 40310784$ but common denominator $50\cdot 2\phi(6^{i-2})$.

Comment: @MartinRubey, you're absolutely right. I should have known better than to stop testing at $i=10$. This multiplication by $5\cdot10^{i-11}$ when $i\geq11$ seems to continue as the common denominator for $i=13$ is $500\cdot 2\phi(6^{i-2})$ and for $i=18$ it's $50000000\cdot 2\phi(6^{i-2})$.

Comment: For $i=21,22,23,24$ the common denominator is $7^{i-21}\cdot 5\cdot 10^{i-11}\cdot 2 \phi(6^{i-2})$.

Comment: Could you post the complete list of denominators?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70004/discussion-between-yacoub-kureh-and-martin-rubey).